# How can i add a delay to pressing buttons in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am very new to programming so please have patience with me. I am trying to add a delay to pressing a button in Unity. For example when i press "S" there should be a specified number of seconds that has to pass before i can press it again. Can anyone help me out ???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a better way to reset cooldown on Unity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32070533/is-there-a-better-way-to-reset-cooldown-on-unity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can i add a delay to pressing buttons in Unity

If you want to achieve that you can set a delayTime and count it down in the Update Method and make the button do nothing on press until the time has passed.

**Example:**

```cs
float time = 0f;

void Update() {
    if (time > 0f){
        // Subtract the difference of the last time the method has been called
        time -= Time.deltaTime;
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown("S") && time <= 0) {
        // Execute code you had in your Button Click function before
        time = 2f;
    }
}
```

If we want to elaborate on your answer we could also make the buttons enabled property disabled as long as the timer is not down to 0.

Example 2:

```cs
float time = 0f;
Button btn; // The Button you want to be unpressable

void Update() {
    if (time > 0f){
        // Subtract the difference of the last time the method has been called
        time -= Time.deltaTime;
        btn.enabled = false;
    }
    else {
        btn.enabled = true;
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown("S") && time <= 0) {
        // Execute Code you had in your Button Click function before
        time = 2f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to have to recall from memory here, but I believe you want to create an enumerator function, something along the lines of:

```cs
IEnumerator OnButtonClicked()
{

}
```

and when your button is clicked, you want to start this coroutine using:

```cs
StartCoroutine(OnButtonClicked());
```

And inside the `OnButtonClicked()` (or whatever you choose to name it), simply call:

```cs
yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
```

and then do whatever you want it to do after the delay, after this.